# PHP runs only partially in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I recently setup a MAMP environment (v3.5)` to test my website locally rather than having to upload to the host.

The PHP works fine on the remote host, in this case the form will submit.

Here's a link: [PHP Form](http://www.nasa.co.mz/contactus.html)

When I run the site locally only `html` and `css` work but the PHP pages show the first few lines of the POST sequence.

Partial run
[image]

This is the content shown in the viewport

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 59 sendername=&senderemail=&contactno=&user_message=&send=Send

As you can probably guess, this is not the result I am expecting. In the normal scenario, the acknowledgment.php page will load with a 'thank you' message.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the MAMP installation that would cause this?

Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: it would be nice if you added the framework tag you're using to the question.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but I don't think you've provided nearly enough information here to get useful answers. I'd recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then editing your question to add some detail.

Comment: @davejal I didn't use any frameworks for this site. It was built from scratch.

Comment: Post the code: there is an error there. Only with a screenshot is nearly impossible to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

- check if you put the method="post" attribute in your form
- check if you close each tag
- Check the version of php on your mamp: `preferences -> php`
- Reeinstall your mamp

in any case if it does not work, you can try manually install php

other think will be that you post your code of file `acknowledge.php` to check for possible errors

I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much for your insight. I am so humbled by the help provided here!

I opened the acknowledgement.php file only to discover that somehow the content had been erased leaving only a few lines.

I corrected it, using the file from the remote host and it is working now!